# Basic Stochastic Calculus: Integration of wiener proces

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

How do one compute the following integral:
$$\int_{a}^{b}dw_u$$when $W_t$ is a wiener process. My initially guess will be $W_b-W_a$, but I cannot argue for that because I am not sure wether I can use "normal" calculus properties for Stoch calculus?

Maybe a good idea will be to look at at the general case:$$\int_{a}^{b}g(u)dw_u$$ for a some function $g$. In my case above $g(x) =1$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your assumption is correct. And no, you cannot use ordinary calculus.
We can use Ito. define $Z_t = W_t$ and  $f(x,t)=x$. Then we have that $f'_x=1$
$$df(Z_t,t) = dZ_t=1\text{ } dW_t$$
Now $Z$ can be written in integral form:
$$Z_t=Z_s+\int_{s}^{t}0*du+\int_{s}^{t}1*dW_u$$
for $s<t$. Recall how $Z$ is defined and replace with $W$:
$$W_t=W_s+\int_{s}^{t}dW_u \Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\int_{s}^{t}dW_u=W_t-W_s$$

Comment: I am not an experience professional in this field so there might be some flaws with my arguments. I ask for understanding, thanks